# Can universe still expand without energy and matter?

Tags: general-relativity, space-expansion, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I heard dark energy is the intrinsic property of space and it cannot be particle because particle's density dilute when volume increase, I do not know how nothingness can have property and Einstein came up with a cosmological constant to fix his static universe model therefore mathematically he proved that space by itself can expand. Imagine a universe where empty space is devoided of energy and matter, can it expand?

Comment: Dark energy isn't exactly the cause of expansion. Dark energy causes the expansion to *accelerate*. A cosmological constant causes a constant rate of expansion (or contraction).

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy

Comment: A cosmological constant does not cause a constant rate of expansion, which would be $a\propto t$; it causes exponential expansion, $a\propto e^{Ht}$. I think you meant to say that a cosmological constant causes a constant Hubble parameter, which is $\dot{a}/a$, not $\dot{a}$.

Comment: The model I'm referring to is called Einstein blunder as the author of the science journal said, i also know there are many other models such as phantom field and one which requires us to know the true energy of higgs field instead of lowest potential and many more. Hope it clear up the confusion, thanks.

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/dareng.html

Comment: @G.Smith You are perfectly correct. I shouldn't post when I'm falling asleep. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universe can expand without matter or radiation, but it cannot expand without energy. You can have “dark energy” without either matter or radiation.

In fact, right now dark energy is driving the accelerating expansion of our unverse, and the matter and radiation in it are playing a diminishing role. In the current standard cosmologcal model, the effect of matter and radiation will become negligible and the dark energy will cause exponential expansion.

You should not think of spacetime as nothingness. It has nontrivial geometric structure and the metric field that determines its geometry can carry energy, momentum, and angular momentum from place to place just like the electromagnetic field does.

Comment: Do you have any links? the reason we know about dark energy is because of its effects on matter and radiation that we observe and quantify. A hypothetical universe without matter and radiation  cannot be recorded, even if the mathematics exists for such a model, imo.

Comment: The philosophical issue you raise is not one that physics can settle. Everyone agrees on the math, and it seems obvious to me, based on our current understanding, that the universe will keep expanding due to dark energy even as the matter and radiation in it dilute to insignificance. I don’t think it’s going to care that no one may be around to record it. I am not in the camp that thinks consciousness creates the universe or keeps it going.

Comment: That is another story, of how the present model evolves, and different from starting with nonexistence of matter and energy. It is not philosophic, it is how models fit data and if data exist. In the present universe model the standard model is postulated. in an empty of radiation and matter universe this standard model cannot be assumed., because there would have been in the beginning matter and radiation and remnants all the way to infinity

Comment: Obviously there is no data for a universe without matter and radiation. There is only a mathematical model for such a thing.

Comment: that is why I asked for a link.

Comment: The einstein equation depend on space time  on one side and the energy momentum tensor on the other. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity#Einstein's_equations If there is no energy momentum  how can there be varience in space time ? you mean a generic dark energy four vector?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_universe

Comment: OK, thanks for the link. This means that you assume no standard model which develops particles and radiation, just dark energy as in the beginning of the BB

Comment: You can put a cosmological constant on the spacetime side, or you can put vacuum energy-momentum or scalar field energy-momentum on the energy-momentum side.

Comment: In a true deSitter universe, there is no matter and radiation at all, from the beginning. But, as the article explains, our universe is approaching a deSitter universe as matter and radiation thin out.

Comment: SE is telling me to avoid an extended discussion.

Comment: @G.Smith When you say "The universe can expand without matter or radiation, but it cannot expand without energy. You can have 'dark energy' without either matter or radiation". It sounds like matter cannot be described by energy, or they are totally independent things. But as you know the Friedmann Equation actually contains the energy density which is the sum of the matter-energy density, radiation energy density etc.
Second thing is,

Comment: The universe can expand without dark energy. For example, in a flat matter dominated universe, the $a(t)=(t/t_0)^{2/3}$ scale factor increases. It's not accelerated expansion, but the universe keeps expanding.